# Thread after Service is destroyed

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an android `Service` called `MyService`.

I have an `Activity` with two buttons (start service/stop service).

When user clicks the button "start service", `MyService` is started using

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

When user clicks the button "stop service", `MyService` is stopped using

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

In `MyService` I create a `Thread` `T` that performs some long running task.

My question is: If the `Service` is destroyed, is `T` also destroyed even if it is still running?

Comment: What do you see happening when you write a sample app to do this?

Comment: In my app after the Service is destroyed the thread is still running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ending a thread you explicitly created is not the responsibility of the Android framework. You need to extend `onDestroy()`. Here is the javadoc for this method:

> Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed. The service should clean up an resources it holds (threads, registered receivers, etc) at this point. Upon return, there will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively dead. Do not call this method directly.

I would also suggest that you make your thread use [Interrupts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) so that you can end it gracefully.